# Displaying informations to fill the width?

Tags: website-design, information

I have the following page I am working on :[image]

What bothers me, is am I right to display the informations under the picture like I did ?

I wonder if it's good to fill the width space with boxes next to each other.

Also I am asking myself this question because I want the left part of the page to be quite long (there should be an ad on the right part, for example if there is no photo, it will be weird).

Any feedback appreciated ;)

Thanks

Comment: You aren't posing a UX question here.  It seems more like a site review request, which is off topic, and hence I am putting the question on hold.